# The first while loop of the nested loop iterates only once

Tags: java, string, while-loop, iteration, nested-loops

Comparing two .txt files here, results the line number of the first file if any string in the second file matches or repeats in the first.

Here in the code, the first while loop iterates only once.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(firstFile);
 Scanner scanner1 =new Scanner(secondFile);
 int lineNum = 0;
 while (scanner.hasNextLine())  
  {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        lineNum++;
        while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) 
        {
               String line1 = scanner1.nextLine();
               if(line.contains(line1)) 
                { 
                  System.out.println("Ignore/Review line number: "+lineNum);      
                }
        }
  }
```

Comment: I would use `BufferedReader` or even `LineNumberReader` instead of `Scanner` to just read lines. Actually, depending on file size, I would consider reading at least one complete file and store its lines in a List to avoid having to read it for each line of the other file...

Comment: Saving the second file in the list seems to be a good option. I will try, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the `Scanner` of the second file inside the outer `while` loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(firstFile);
int lineNum = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    lineNum++;
    Scanner scanner1 =new Scanner(secondFile);
    while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
        String line1 = scanner1.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(line1)) { 
            System.out.println("Ignore/Review line number: "+lineNum);      
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise `scanner1.hasNextLine()` returns `false` on the second iteration of the outer `while` loop, since the entire second file was already read on the first iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for making me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` of the second file reads the entire file during the first loop of the outer one amd reaches the end of the file (has nothing to read with next outer while loops). You should create the second `Scanner` in body of the outer while loop to make it read the chosen second file from the beginning with the every start of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the fact that the second while loop is never canceled. Thus, when you find a matching line in file 2, you go on comparing the line of file 1 to all other lines in file 2. What you probably want is something like this:

```
if(line.contains(line1)) 
{ 
    System.out.println("Ignore/Review line number: "+lineNum);
    break;
}
```

After this, you can go on comparing the next line of file 1 to the next line of file 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not comparing 2nd line with 2nd line. Comparing whole file with one line of the other file at a time then iterating the line (other file). I have found my answer clear-cut.